# How can I type annotate a PyMongo Collection?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, typing

I'm currently using:

```
from typing import Type
from pymongo.collection import Collection

def collection_type_test(example_collection: Type[Collection]) -> list:
    return list(example_collection.find())
```

Is this the correct approach, will I get any linter benefits from this / any benefits at all?

Comment: Why `Type[Collection]`?! Apparently you're not expecting a type, you're expecting an instance.

Comment: Didn't realise a class definition itself counted as a type / that a class definition is just the type of the instances you then create. Thanks!

Comment: That's because 99% of the time you do mean *instance of*, and there's no sensible way to denote "instance of" something when you just have the class…

Answer (score 3):

For me it went to use `Collection` directly:

```py
from pymongo.collection import Collection

def collection_type_test(example_collection: Collection) -> list:
    return list(example_collection.find())
```